# how to cut the strings before a particular strings in sql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, mysql-error-1093

Device_Users

1. R90FDJMVAdministrator
2. PG04373Administrator

I only want administrator in this field what update query should I run

Answer (score 0):

You can use CHARINDEX practical because you can set a starting point for the search in the string, useful if you know how long is your prefix (I have put 6 but it depends on your data)

UPDATE table 
SET column = 'Administrator' 
WHERE CHARINDEX('Administrator',column,6) > 0

If needed you can refine the WHERE clause to make sure you're not replacing entries which have something after Administrator

AND LEN(column) = CHARINDEX('Administrator',column,6) + LEN('Administrator')

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is good enough:

```
update Device_Users 
set field = 'Administrator' 
where field like '%Administrator'
```